# ConvertJSONtoSQL in apache nifi

Tags: sql, json, type-conversion, etl, apache-nifi

I'm trying to insert in MySQL database my JSON info I have made a lot of JSON like this with split JSON

```
{"type_interaction":"posts_viewed","Author":{"value":"karimee._____"},"Time":{"timestamp":1705789185}}
```

Now I want to use `ConvertJsonToSQL` to get an

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (type_interaction, author_value, time_timestamp) VALUES ('$type_interaction', '$author_value', $time_timestamp)"
```

Then I want to introduce it to `PutSQL` in MySQL database, I need help, But I don't know how to make this, i tried and I get something like this

```
INSERT INTO Interactions (type_interaction) VALUES (?)
```

what must I do?